# Сетка по полигону и как ее делать

Tags: java, android, unity3d

Что нужно: поделить полигон в юнити сеткой (допустим 10 в высоту 5 в ширину), и при нажатии на экран в рандомной ячейке появляется объект.
Что я пытался сделать: создал в цикле двумерный массив координат центров ячеек. И сделал рандомнойячейке выбор из массива.
Я глубоко сомневаюсь что это правильно и хотел бы узнать как можно решить эту задачу иначе?

Comment: хороший вариант, что не так? можно конечно не делать двухмерный массив, для рандомизации хватит и одномерного

Comment: А если использовать сетку с не фиксированной высотой или очень длинную то как быть..

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров использовать List/ArrayList очевидно)